# Source: Male & Female Mitzvot Quote

Tags: sources-mekorot, women, mitzvah

I remember a phrase along the lines of "the virtue of a woman comes from her birth and the virtue of a man comes from his actions" in relation to mitzvot, but I cannot recall/determine its origin or if has been corrupted in my mind over time. But I could have sworn it was something scriptural? Or perhaps from commentary?

Is this something that is actually written somewhere in some form? Or did I just imagine this?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! While not an exact quote (and I don't have the source offhand, which is why I'm leaving this as a comment instead of an answer), I've heard this idea said in regards to the idea of why women have a different set of Mitzvah obligations (i.e. exempt on time-bound Mitzvos). Male souls need to accomplish more in order to achieve a higher spiritual plane, while female souls start off on a higher spiritual plane, so they need less Mitzvos to reach spiritual heights.

Comment: @Salmononius2 People just say that for political correctness. Being on a spiritual plane without working for it is meaningless in Judaism, hence the need for a yetzer hara. Otherwise we would all just be malachim.